# Unique Jobs in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, caching, locking

I have a legacy application in laravel 5.2 and we use queues to process jobs. We observed that the queue can sometimes get too many jobs which leads to duplicate jobs getting dispatched because the previous jobs don't complete processing and the cron that dispatches such jobs runs again and ends up dispatching them over and over.

A simple solution would be to make these jobs unique which would be a very simple change if it were laravel 8. However, we're in laravel 5.2 territory so i'll have to implement unique jobs myself. Or if someone could suggest a better alternative?

Also, if you were to implement unique jobs yourself, how would you do it?
The approach I'm thinking is:

Add a unique key for the job to the cache or a database table (implying a lock is attained)
Clear the entry once the job is processed (lock released)
Before dispatching the job, check if the key exists in the cache or not (lock can be attained or not)

Comment: This is really vague. For example in my naive head, if your cron won't dispatch jobs that were previously completed can't you modify it to not dispatch jobs that were previously dispatched? I feel like there might be a whole lot of these questions popping up because there's no real detail of your process here other than a vague description

Comment: use `withoutoverlapping` and `onQueue` option while dispatching jobs.

Comment: You described a good solution in your last part. Lock (aka mutex) is intended for this use case. Just one thing, i would check for the lock inside the job also. Since between the dispatch and the job execution could have some time i think it's more reliable.

Comment: @SachinKumar laravel 5.2 does not have the `withoutoverlapping` option

Comment: so they may opt for putting the job on queues!

Comment: @apokryfos that is what I wish to achieve through unique jobs. I could edit the cron to check that but I was aiming for a more generic solution which could be applied on all existing jobs. Apologies for the vagueness, can you describe what details should I elaborate on?
A generic description of the problem is that "I need to replicate the unique jobs functionality in laravel 5.2 since laravel allows pushing duplicate jobs on a queue"

Comment: @ml59 thanks that's what I observed is happening in the laravel 8 implementation [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/55ea49b4f49269b3ea78415f106b308ef8d7ce71/src/Illuminate/Queue/Middleware/WithoutOverlapping.php#L63). I wouldn't have thought of checking within the job as well but will do that as well!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on the discussions under comments and some more help from the internet, I went ahead with the following:

1. Create a unique id for the jobs
2. Acquire a lock using the unique id and store it in the cache
3. If the lock was acquired, dispatch the job
4. After the job's completion, release the lock from the cache

May not be the best implementation but definitely meets our requirement.

Code:

Common helper functions to acquire a lock before dispatching jobs:

```
/**
 * Acquires a lock but storing a key on the cache for the provided duration
 * the `$jobInstance` must have a `jobId()` function that provides a unique id
 * for the job used to prevent duplicacy
 *
 * @var  Job  $jobInstance  a Job instance to acquire a lock for
 * @var  int  $minutes  number of minutes to hold the lock for (default: 1 day)
 *
 * @return  bool
 */
function acquireLock($jobInstance, $minutes = 1440)
{
    $lockAcquired = false;
    try {
        DB::beginTransaction();
        /**
         * If the job instance does not provide a `jobId` function do not
         * attempt to acquire a lock for it
         */
        $jobId = method_exists($jobInstance, 'jobId') ? $jobInstance->jobId() : null;
        if (!is_null($jobId)) {
            $isLockAvailable = is_null(Cache::get($jobId));
            if ($isLockAvailable) {
                Cache::put($jobId, true, $minutes);
                $lockAcquired = true;
            }
        }
        DB::commit();
    } catch (\Throwable $th) {
        DB::rollback();
        Log::error("Unable to acquire lock");
        Log::error($th);
    }
    return $lockAcquired;
}

/**
 * Attempts to acquires a lock for the job and dispatches it
 * if the lock was successfull acquired
 *
 * @var  Job  $jobInstance  Job instance to dispatch
 *
 * @return void
 */
function dispatchWithLock($jobInstance)
{
    $isLockAcquired = acquireLock($jobInstance);
    if ($isLockAcquired) {
        dispatch($jobInstance);
    }
}
```

Added a listener on `AppServiceProvider` to release the locks

```
Queue::after(function (JobProcessed $event) {
    /**
     * Check if the job has a `jobId` function and release the lock used to
     * maintain job uniqueness
     */
    $jobInstance = unserialize($event->data['data']['command']);
    $jobId = method_exists($jobInstance, 'jobId')
            ? $jobInstance->jobId()
            : null;
    if (!is_null($jobId)) {
        Cache::forget($jobId);
    }
});
```

Added a `jobId` function to jobs that need to be unique

```
/**
 * Get a unique id for the job to prevent duplicates
 *
 * @return str
 */
public function jobId()
{
    return str_slug(get_class($this)) . $this->myModel->id;
}
```

Finally dispatch jobs with the helper function

```
dispatchWithLock(new myJob($this));
```